# how to save the code in one blog page and the code will not be changed in code of this blog page?

Tags: html, xml, blogs

```
  @"//div[@id='transcriptText']/div[@class='notranslate']/p/a/@href"];

   @"//div[@id='videoPlayerSWF']/noscript/div/p/a/@href"];

    @"//div[@id='transcriptText']/div/p/a/text()"];

    @"//div[@id='transcriptText']/div/p/a/text()"];
```

how to save the code in one  blog page  and the code will not be changed in code of this blog page?

i past the 4 line code to my one yahoo blog,

but i Analysis the code of this one yahoo blog page,  the charater has been changed.

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="ted | Blog | wert&#039;s blog" />
<meta property="og:description" content="  @&amp;quot;//div[@id=&amp;#039;transcriptText&amp;#039;]/div[@class=&amp;#039;notranslate&amp;#039;]/p/a/@href&amp;quot;];








   @&amp;quot;//div[@id=&amp;#039;videoPlayerSWF&amp;#039;]/noscript/div/p/a/@href&amp;quot;];








    @&amp;quot;//div[@id=&amp;#039;transcriptText&amp;#039;]/div/p/a/text()&amp;quot;];








    @&amp;quot;//div[@id=&amp;#039;transcriptText&amp;#039;]/div/p/a/text()&amp;quot;];" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://l.yimg.com/op/images/ico_product_56.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Yahoo! Blog" />
```

how to do, the charater will not been changed ?

Answer (score 0):

it is solved by this way.

```
<pre><code>@"//div[@id='transcriptText']/div[@class='notranslate']/p/a/@href"];

 @"//div[@id='videoPlayerSWF']/noscript/div/p/a/@href"];

 @"//div[@id='transcriptText']/div/p/a/text()"];

 @"//div[@id='transcriptText']/div/p/a/text()"];
</code></pre>
```